# Navigation bar not toggling between classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm trying to make my navigation bar responsive, but my hamburger menu button doesn't seem to toggle between classes `.ul` and' `.show` showing error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined`.

How can I fix this?

Is there a way to transition the navigation bar from the top?

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('bars');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('.ul')[0].classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```html
<div class="navbar-links">
  <i class="fa fa-bars" id="bars"></i>
  <ul class="ul">
    <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `.` inside `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('bars');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('navItems')[0].classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```html
<div class="navbar-links">
  <i class="fa fa-bars" id="bars"></i>
  <ul class="navItems">
    <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```